# Where I can find reference on Katetov's extension $kN$ of the natural numbers?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I’m looking for references on Katetov's extension $kN$ of the natural numbers? However I cannot find it. Is this separable and is this a countable union of closed discrete subspace of it?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264109/what-is-katetov-extension-of-the-natural-numbers) has a definition and a reference to [the original paper](https://eudml.org/doc/25138). And $kN \setminus N$ is itself closed and discrete, and we can add the singletons of $N$ to see that indeed this space is a countable union of closed and discrete subspaces. $N$ is dense in $kN$ so $kN$ is of course separable.

Comment: The original paper is too old and I cannot get it from the link.

Comment: Is this space separable?

Comment: @Paul: Yes, it’s separable: $\Bbb N$ is dense in it. Katětov’s original paper is freely available [here](https://eudml.org/doc/25138); the other paper seems not to be available now.

Comment: @Paul: [Here](http://www.math.uaic.ro/~annalsmath/pdf-uri%20anale/F1-2009/Mukherjee.pdf) is a direct link to the Mukherjee et al. PDF.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thanks for the link!

Comment: @Paul: You’re welcome!